# Traefik v2 - Enable gzip compression

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, traefik

I am using Traefik v2 to running a Docker container. This container is serving with Nginx and I need to enable gzip compression on Traefik v2.

I couldn't achieve it by changing the Nginx app.config file.

I added these kinds of tags but it didn't work.

```
gzip on;
gzip_types images, CSS, js etc.
```

How can I enable gzip on a Traefik v2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this is the **Simplest** way to enable gzip.

Open Traefik v2 `docker-compose.yml` and add these lines:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.2.7
    container_name: traefik

labels:
.
.
.
// paste on the last line to enable gzip compression
- "traefik.http.routers.traefik.middlewares=traefik-compress"
- "traefik.http.middlewares.traefik-compress.compress=true"
```

Open Your Container's docker-compose.yml and add these lines:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
    your_container_name:

labels:
.
.
.
// paste on the last line to enable gzip compression
- "traefik.http.middlewares.your_container_name_compress.compress=true"
- "traefik.http.routers.your_container_name.middlewares=your_container_name_compress"
```

Then, run your both `docker-compose.yml` files.

You may also find this solution as a Gist: https://gist.github.com/fatihyildizhan/e1d9d909049f0a67a7d1585468193438

Full Traefik v1 and v2 install guide with Let's Encrypt: https://gist.github.com/fatihyildizhan/8f124039a9bd3801f0caf3c01c3601fb

Updated on 18 May 2023: `Docker 23 + Traefik 2.9.10 and v1.7 + Let's Encrypt + Github Registry V2 ghcr.io`

Comment: This works for me... but I only needed to configure compression on the child container. I did not need to modify the configuration of the Traefik host container.